# How to get value of key 1 where key 2 equals value 2? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this array object:

```
color =[{"id":"1", "name":"black"},{"id":"2", "name":"white"}]
```

And I have a value `1` from `$scope.object.id = 1`

So I'm trying to get color name where color id = $scope.object.id. How do I do this?

I have this code in my html:

```
<select ng-model="color" ng-options="color.name for color in colorList" class='material-options'></select>
```

How do i use that value the default select option?

Comment: Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). `var arr= color.filter(function(e) { return e.id === 1 }); if (arr.length) { console.log(arr.name); }`

Comment: If you are using Underscore or Lodash you can use the `_.find(color, { id: $scope.object.id })` to return the object, then access the name property on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the `filter` method.

```
var clr = color.filter(function(item){ return item.id === $scope.object.id; });
```

Then you can read the `name` value as below:

```
var name = clr.length === 1 ? clr[0].name : '';
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

That being sad, this is why we do the extra check for the `length` of the `clr`. Given your context, there should be only one color with this `id` or none. So, the array that `filter` would create and return would be either of length 0 or 1.

Comment: I have this code in my html:      `<select ng-model="color" ng-options="color.name for color in colorList" class='material-options'></select>` How do i place that value I get from var name as the default select option?

Comment: Have a look please here http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/